# SQLContext Wrapper

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a wrapper of SQLContext which should enable the below sql method (sqlc.sql) to run the query up to least 3times before failing. For every fail re-try, the spark context should be closed and re-started.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc=SparkContext()
sqlc=SQLContext()
sqlc.sql("select * from table").write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("new_table")
```

Currently I am doing it as below

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext

global sc
global sqlc

sc=SparkContext()
sqlc=SQLContext()

for i in range(1,4):
     try:
          sqlc.sql("select * from table").write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("new_table")
          break
     exception e:
          sc.stop()
          sc=SparkContext()
          sqlc=SQLContext(sc)
```

As I need to apply these changes to 100s of python scripts, I want this logic to apply internally when I call sqlc.sql method.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably to write a decorator, something like:

```
import logging
import time

# create a decorator that will retry a function if it fails
def retry_on_exception(max_retries=3, retry_interval=1):
    def wrapper(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            retries = 0
            while retries < max_retries:
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    retries += 1
                    logging.error(f"SQL query failed with error: {e}. Retrying (attempt {retries}/{max_retries})...")
                    # You can restart SparkContext here if you want
                    time.sleep(retry_interval)
            raise Exception(f"SQL query failed after {max_retries} attempts.")
        return wrapped
    return wrapper

# use the retry wrapper with the query function
@retry_on_exception(max_retries=2, retry_interval=1)
def execute_sql_query(query):
    # Code to execute the SQL query goes here
    # raise Exception("SQL query failed.") # example of failure
    return "this" # example of success

# call the query function
execute_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table")
```

That being said: restarting the SparkContext every time might not be recommended, it might be better to try to find out why the query is failing and address the root cause instead of restarting the context.

Second note: there is also a python package 'retry' that can do a lot of advanced things out of the box, see [here](https://pypi.org/project/retry/)

Hope this helps